# Does LaTeX _cache_ PDF images that were trimmed with `includegraphics[trim ...]`?

Tags: graphics, overleaf, live-preview

I used the command

```
\includegraphics[trim=100 280 100 100,clip,width=10cm]{examplefigure.pdf}
```

and noted that, when I changed the figure in my computer and uploaded it again to `Overleaf`, the picture showed in the preview was the old one, without my changes, even after using the `recompile from scratch` option.

After trying many solutions for that problem, I had the idea of simply changing one of the values in `trim= 100 280 100 100` by a little amount: `trim= 100 270 100 100`. Then, the new figure showed up.

Do you know why that happens? Would that only happen in Overleaf? Or is it common everywhere?

**Edit**:

It seems it's a bug in Overleaf preview. I used the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim=100 220 100 100,clip,width=10cm]{examplefigure.pdf} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and uploaded two pdf's called `examplefigure.pdf` and `examplefigure-2.pdf`. Apparently I can't upload pdf images here to show you, so I send you my MWE project editable link (I hope this is a safe thing to do):

https://www.overleaf.com/4270057yrcdqx

Then, I changed the figure name in `includegraphics` many times and noted that the preview didn't update unless I changed `trim` options. However, I found that, when I download the PDF, the right, updated version is downloaded.

I guess it's a bug in Overleaf preview that I should report to them.

Comment: No (could guess but insufficient info to be worthwhile). No. No.

Comment: Editable MWE added to this question.

Comment: If the downloaded PDF is correct, I think you must be right and should report to Overleaf. It doesn't look like a TeX issue in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a co-founder of Overleaf. Yep, that's a bug. Thanks for the MWE --- we'll try to get that fixed! In the mean time, if you change the trim or something else on the page, the preview will update. And, as you noticed, the PDF itself will show the right image if you download it.